# Is there a way to convert a list of cc'es to a distribution list in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

In Outlook 2003, I find myself frequently sending emails to the same group of people all working on a project.  I'd like to find a simple way to convert the list of addresses in an email that I would "reply all" to into an Outlook distribution list for future use.

I know how to create Outlook distribution lists, that's not my question.  But the normal process that I see in Outlook requires adding the names to the list one by one.  If I have an email with a large "reply all" list is there any way to take that whole list all at once (including many email addresses not otherwise already in my Outlook contacts) and convert it to a distribution list in one step?

Trying to google for this answer got me many, many pages of instructions on how to create a distribution list, but I can't seem to find the search term to locate an answer on how to convert a list of address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Outlook2003 on an Exchange server and here's my partial suggestion:

If I open an email (or look at it in the preview pane), select all the CC'd users (right-click - Select All) and copy; I can then paste this in to the **Members** field in the **Select Members** window when creating a distribution list. It only seems to copy the name but it then matches the names up nicely to thier exchange accounts (although in one case I did get the Check Names box, as we have two accounts with effectively identically named people).

I'm not sure how it responds to "normal" emails, as opposed to other users accounts on the same exchange server, you would have to test.

Not a perfect solution by far, but might be sufficent for infrequent use.

Comment: This does not work at all for external email addresses.

Comment: Damn. Well, as worth a try. I don't get much (read: any) external email at work so didn't have the opportunity to test.
Hopefully someone can come up with a valid answer for you.